# access to variable outside javascript loop

Tags: javascript, sorting, time, utc

Here is my code below. I am using the UTC timestamp to properly sort the data but want to convert to local time after its sorted (which the last 2 commented lines do). However if I convert before I sort then the results are not correct. If I try to convert outside the function, there is no context to b.Timestamp.

```
var myArray = [];

data.Items.forEach(function(b) {
    myArray.push(b.Timestamp + "text" + b.payload.value );
});

myArray.sort();

//var date = new Date(b.Timestamp + 'UTC');
//date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages sometime.  You should probably tag this with the host language — I suspect it is JavaScript, but I could be wrong.  It will get your question in front of people with the relevant expertise better than the current tags.  You should drop [tag:local]; that has a purpose unrelated to time.  It's not clear that [tag:arrays] is all that important, for all you're using an array.

Comment: Don't you just use another loop over the sorted array, apply the conversion to the value in the array?

Comment: hi Jonathan - I believe you are correct but I am having a hard time getting it to work. I am not sure how to access b.Timestamp outside of the original loop. There is no context to b.

Answer (score 0):

You have to preserve the original array while you sort, then transform it. You can do this by passing a custom comparison function to `.sort()`. Here's a chained implementation:

```
// Get a string sort key for an item
function sortKey(item) {
    return item.Timestamp + item.payload.value;
}

var myArray = data.Items
    // Copy the array to avoid modifying the original
    .slice()
    // Sort using custom logic
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return sortKey(a) > sortKey(b) ? 1 : -1;
    })
    // Use map to transform
    .map(function(b) {
        return Date(b.Timestamp + 'UTC');
    });
```